# How to manually define a method after "def create" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, I'm pretty new to rails & am pretty certain I didn't ask the question using the correct terminology so here's an example of what I'm trying to do

I have this in my controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:order])
  if @order.save
    @token = DownloadToken.create
    @post.status => "POSTED" #"POSTED" IS WHAT I WANT STORED UNDER THAT POST'S STATUS IF SAVED
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Now, this isn't exactly what I want done but is similar to what I'd like to do. Again, I'm still very new to rails. Is there any way for me to set this manually?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an after_create hook in your model

```
class Post
  after_create :set_status

  private

    def set_status
      self.update_attribute(:status, "POSTED")
    end

end
```

or you can simple update the record in your controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:order])
  if @order.save
    @token = DownloadToken.create
    @post.update_attribute(:status, "POSTED")
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: ok.. "update_attribute".. I was familiar with "after_create" but never thought to use it this way... I'm starting to wrap my head around ROR. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) might be what you are looking for.

It will enable you to do the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create do
    self.status = "POSTED"
  end
end
```

I did use `before_create` here, as you want to create a new object in your sample code. The `before_create` callback will only be called when a new record is created, as opposed to `before_save`, which will be called anytime the model is saved.